# Why is "pages" in my tab site name - Pages - Home

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using SharePoint Online and have Publishing turned on.
However, the tab for my site displays Pages - UAT Home.

Why does it have Pages in front of it?
I have attempted to edit properties, to no avail.  I cannot see how to remove the "Pages" reference from the tab.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior.

Instead create a page in the root folder (outside pages library) and set it as the home page.

You can use SharePoint Designer for creating page in the root folder.